# SQL Query Using Primary Key

Tags: sql, indexing, key, sql-update

I have a SQL table with three columns (key, id, loglevel). The key column is set as the primary key, and is auto-incremented.

Imagine this:

```
key   id   loglevel
1     223     5
2     445     8
```

Now I want to update the table by selecting the row thata corresponds to a specific value of "key".

I am using the line:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE Logs SET loglevel = 4 WHERE key = 2;");
```

However this doesn't work.

When I change it to

```
mysql_query("UPDATE Logs SET loglevel = 4 WHERE id = 445;");
```

it works fine. However, I want to update based on "key" and not "id".

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: is MySQL generating an error message? if so, what is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In MySQL key is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html) and must be quoted.

```
"UPDATE Logs SET loglevel = 4 WHERE `key` = 2"
```

I'd also strongly recommend that you look at the value of [mysql_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) when your query fails as this may have given you the hint you needed to solve this yourself.

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key' at line 1

Comment: hmm...no error message came up, but i changed the name from key, so thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

"key" is a reserved word in MySQL (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).  I would suggest using a word other then 'key' as your Primary Key as it could be confusing later to have a column named 'key' and another named 'id' as a common convention is to use 'id' as the Primary Key...